# Increase/Decrease size of table view cell on tap - Swift

Tags: swift

I realise this has been asked before but all implementations are to do with height for row at index however I have static cells which have multiple heights.

I can't figure out how to increase the size of cell at index 0 to 100% height of the screen.

I have implemented didSelectRowAtIndexPath so I can check if cell 0 is tapped but unsure how to increase the height.

Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `heightForRowAtIndexPathMethod` and check if the cell is tapped ( you said that you have checker for that). If you want whole screen you can use something like `UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height` or something like this.

Also, for nice animation you can use

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

To be more concrete about the implementation, you can set following:

```
if(checker == true){
     return UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height
}
else{
     return 44 // default row value 
}
```